# Got an error reading communication packets in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am getting the MySQL error

> "Got an error reading communication packets"

in MySQL.err file and in my application side I am getting 2013 error (lost connection during query).

All the timeout values are (in seconds):

```
wait_timeout = 60
net_read_timeout = 30
connect_timeout = 30
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: maybe try a keepalive to ensure the connection isnt closed?

Answer (score 2):

For what this is worth, this vague error is somewhat common with many possible culprits.

Often it is not a problem with MySql per say...but the system or calling program instead.  eg Sometimes you have php memory limits set to low or the swap drive was never setup...that crashes PHP and MySQL is left confused as to what happened.

In my case, I didn't have that, but I was trying to do a json_encode on a character string with non-utf8 characters which would fail silently and drag mysql down with it.  On top of this OPCache in PHP7 seems to be seriously buggy and lacks proper error logging.  I had to disable that as well...then magically all my problems with "communication packets" in /var/log/mysql/error.log went away.

Hope this helps someone...gave me a LOT of grief.

Comment: You saved my day.In my case php-fpm was crushing. I checked dmesg and found that `php-fpm[6489]: segfault at 28 ip 00007f4382ac8c55 sp 00007ffe277e3280 error 4 in libGeoIP.so.1.6.11`

Comment: @viktor so how do you manage to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Another very weird corner case: check your RAM and your swap!

If you have not enough RAM and swap space, your operating system may decide to kill processes causing your exact error in case of MySQL (`Got an error reading communication packets`). This is a common situation in virtual machines where the provider often does not install any partition for the swap (and when often people does not pay enough RAM).

So, double-check with `top` or `htop` to verify if you have ~100% of your RAM in use or if you have not enough swap (or not swap space at all).

In that case, buy more RAM or search "how to install swapfile" in your distribution.

If that's not the case, see the other answers. Cheers! :)